# What happens if an answer I downvoted gets undeleted?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, undelete

Seeing the undeletions happening from time to time, I was just wondering what would happen to the *-1* rep that a downvoter gets when downvoting an answer.

[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/215590) states, that all reputation is returned when a post gets *deleted*, but (at least as far as I understand it) it does not explain what will happen on undeletion.

consider following scenarios:

- I downvote an answer (I get -1 rep)
- The answer gets deleted less than 60 days after posting (I get my +1 rep returned)

Now, what will happen if the answer...

- ...gets undeleted less than 60 days after posting? (AFAIK, I will get -1 again.)
- ...gets undeleted less than 60 days after *deletion* but not posting? (Which event does count for the 60 day limit - if any?)
- ...gets undeleted more than 60 days after posting? (will everything stay as is?)
- ...gets undeleted more than 60 days after deletion?

In those four cases, what will happen to my or the answerers reputation? My understanding is, that reputation changes get reverted, but I could not find any information regarding the 60 day cap. Does it affect deleted post at all, or does it solely count for posts that are

> [*visible* on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238)

<sup>(emphasis mine - visible means different things for 10k and <10k users)</sup>

If this is true, another question that arises is: are the days counted continuously? So, if a question gets deleted after two days and undeleted another two days later, does the "days visible on site count" stand at 0, 2 or 4?

---

*note:*
I realize that I ask multiple questions here, but I think that these can be answered with few words and are very closely related as they regard the same mechanism, so they won't require a (too) broad answer.